# Is there a way to close terminal after calling sysExecCmd() in CAPL script?

Tags: capl

I wrote a CAPL script that calls a python script using `sysExecCmd` like `sysExecCmd("python",myParameters,myTree)`, where `myTree` is the current (nested) working tree wrt the current directory the CAPL resides in and `myParameters` are generated at runtime and take care of certain variables.

Problem is: every time `sysExecCmd` is called, it opens a new terminal and each one is persistent. I've tried to call a `exit` command without parameters in the same `myTree` like `sysExecCmd("exit","",myTree)`, but it didn't work (and I didn't had many hopes it should have).

While the solution to the problem is not the central point here (I could do with a workaround and either use a batch or delegate to python to close the terminal somehow), I would like to know if there is a way to close terminals on the fly using CAPL scripts.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go off topic but I have a doubt. How can you exchange data between the script you are running and the simulation that calls such script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, for me it works in this way:

```
sysExecCmd("C:\\Projects\\CANoe\\some_script_to_execute && exit","");
```

Answer (score 2):

&& exit does not always work.

You could also do this with the /c option.

> /c    Carries out the command specified by string and then stops.

Note that I am using sysExec and not sysExecCmd as the latter executes cmd with the /k option:

> /k    Carries out the command specified by string and continues.

```
snprintf(parameters, elcount(parameters), "/c mkdir %s", directoryName);
result = sysExec("cmd.exe", parameters, workingPath);
```